# Unicode decode error when retrieving Twitter data using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, unicode, tweepy

When retrieving Twitter data for a specific Arabic keyword as follows:

```
#imports
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

#setting up the keys
consumer_key = '………….' 
consumer_secret = '…………….'
access_token = '…………..'
access_secret = '……...'

class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    # A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    #This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to standard output

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

    #printing all the tweets to the standard output
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, TweetListener())
    stream.filter(track=['سوريا'])
```

I got this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Mona/Desktop/twitter.py", line 29, in <module>
stream.filter(track=['سوريا'])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site- packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 303, in filter
encoded_track = [s.encode(encoding) for s in track]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please any Help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked at the source code for tweepy and found the line in the source for Stream that [seems to cause the problem](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/8effc5a3c51a976024094c5f69c13c05b2dbfd3d/tweepy/streaming.py#L368). The line is from the filter method. When you call `stream.filter(track=['سوريا'])` in your code, Stream calls 
`s.encode('utf-8')` where s = 'سوريا' (looking at the source code for filter, you'll utf-8 is the default encoding). It is at this point the code throws an exception.

To fix this, we need to use a Unicode string.

```
 t = u"سوريا"
 stream.filter(track=[t])
```

(I just put your string into the variable t for clarity).